# Mongodb return populated object but save empties some fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have a little problem, when I post to save data on the database, it does everything OK and returns the object as it should be, but when I get it from the database it comes with an empty array and I know that I save this array with data.

This is the code:

**Controller**

```
    router.post("/semestre", function(req, res) {
    var req = req;
    var res = res;
    console.log("hello! routed to /semestre [create]");
    //build needs
    var newSemestre = new semestreModel();
    //fecthing materias


    newSemestre.nome = req.body.nome;
    if (req.body.materias.length > 0) {
        var materias = JSON.parse(req.body.materias);
        materias.forEach(function(materia, index) {
            //building needs  
            var newMateria = new materiaModel();
            //fechting avaliacoes
            newMateria.nome = materia.nome;
            newMateria.avaliacoes = [];
            if (materia.avaliacoes.length > 0) {
                materia.avaliacoes.forEach(function(avaliacao, index) {
                    //console.log("avaliacao:" + avaliacao.nome);
                    //building nedds
                    var newAvaliacao = new avaliacaoModel();
                    newAvaliacao.nome = avaliacao.nome;
                    newAvaliacao.nota = avaliacao.nota;
                    newAvaliacao.save(function(err, availacao) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("@semestres [create] - saving avaliacao has error");
                            res.send({ erro: true, msg: "Oops! alguma coisa está errada!" });
                        } else {
                            newMateria.avaliacoes.push(avaliacao._id);
                        }
                    });
                });
            } else {
                console.log("avaliacoes:[]");
            }

            newMateria.save(function(err, materia) {
                if (err) {
                    //console.log(err);
                    console.log("@semestres [create] - saving materia has error");
                    res.send({ erro: true, msg: "Oops! alguma coisa está errada!" });
                } else {
                    newSemestre.materias.push(materia._id);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    newSemestre.save(function(err, semestre) {
        if (err) {
            //console.err(err);
            console.log("saving semestre has error");
            res.send({ erro: true, msg: "Oops! alguma coisa está errada!" });
        } else {
            //console.log(semestre);
            res.send(semestre);
        }
    });

});
```

**Schemas**

```
var materia = {
    nome: String,
    notaFinal:Number,
    semestre_id:String,
    frequencia:Number
  };
var MateriaSchema = new Schema(materia );

var model = {
    nome: String,
    materias: [String],
    completo: Boolean
};
var SemestreSchema = new Schema(model);

var model = {
    nome: String,
    materia_id: String,
    nota: Number
};
var AvaliacaoSchema = new Schema(model);
```

Again everything works fine, but it just saves an empty array of `materias` when creating a `newSemestre`.

Comment: After doing `newSemestre.materias.push(materia._id);` , you can call some function to do `newSemestre.save`, which will work as expected.

Comment: i do that at the end

Comment: That won't help you. Because it is asynchronous. It won't wait for the save of `materia` to be finished before doing save for `newsemester` . So there will be empty array to be saved for semester.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following way :-

```
var newSemestre = new semestreModel();
//fecthing materias

newSemestre.nome = req.body.nome;
if (req.body.materias.length > 0) 
{
    var materias = JSON.parse(req.body.materias);
    materias.forEach(function(materia, parentIndex) 
   {
        //building needs  
        var newMateria = new materiaModel();
        //fechting avaliacoes
        newMateria.nome = materia.nome;
        newMateria.avaliacoes = [];
        if (materia.avaliacoes.length > 0)
        {
            materia.avaliacoes.forEach(function(avaliacao, index)
           {
                //console.log("avaliacao:" + avaliacao.nome);
                //building nedds
                var newAvaliacao = new avaliacaoModel();
                newAvaliacao.nome = avaliacao.nome;
                newAvaliacao.nota = avaliacao.nota;
                newAvaliacao.save(function(err, availacao) 
                 {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("@semestres [create] - saving avaliacao has error");
                        res.send({ erro: true, msg: "Oops! alguma coisa está errada!" });
                    } else {
                        newMateria.avaliacoes.push(avaliacao._id);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("avaliacoes:[]");
        }

        newMateria.save(function(err, materia) 
        {
            if (err) 
           {
                //console.log(err);
                console.log("@semestres [create] - saving materia has error");
                res.send({ erro: true, msg: "Oops! alguma coisa está errada!" });
            } 
            else
            {
                newSemestre.materias.push(materia._id);

                //If the last loop of "foreach" is going on, then only call the function, which will do save.
                if(parentIndex > req.body.materias.length)
                {
                      saveSemester(); // call some function
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

});
```

The function goes here.

```
function saveSemester()
{
    // do stuff to save semester
}
```

The empty array, saved, because before you are trying to save semester, there is no data in that array. So you need to wait for the push to be done and then proceed to do save, which will save the data you want.

**UPDATE**

Updated my answer. Function will be called once the last loop is going on of foreach. This is what I could think of right now.

Hope this will help.

Comment: so, there is a problem about this solution, i have a foreach runing and if i put that function call there where you suggested it will be called each time the foreach runs, so i cant use that.

Comment: Are you using [async - node js](https://github.com/caolan/async)? I am using async to handle this kind of situations.

Comment: no i'm not using it, but i'll take a look, and thx again, btw, i had thought that but i did not tried it yet, i'm actually doing some college work now, so i'm going to do that later